# Move JavaScript to Bottom of ASPX page in order to reduce PageLoad

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance

In my WebApplication i am having many ASPX pages each contain Lot of javaScript at the Beginning of page.
This Increases the Loading time of the page (40 sec min).
I know javascript @ beginning of page will block page rendering and the loading time will be increased.
How can i move Javascript to bottom of page without loss of actual functionality in order to reduce page loading time.

Comment: Are you using 'ClientScriptManager` to manage scripts?

Comment: Yes. We are using ClientScriptManager

Answer (score 2):

[`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)  (and I think `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude`) will render the script block towards the top of the `form` element, whereas [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y) will render them towards the bottom of the `form` element.

The problem with `RegisterStartUpScript` is that it does not output scripts in the order they were added, which is very frustrating. You can try a few things:

1. Make sure your script names are alphabetically ordered in the order you want them rendered (stupid, I know).
2. Try implementing your own `ClientScriptManager` that doesn't act so foolishly.
3. Avoid `ClientScriptManager` altogether, emitting scripts into literal blocks exactly where you want the scripts to appear.
4. Bundle your client scripts and just include the bundle.

The problem with #3 and #4 is that controls may check with the `ClientScriptManager` to see if a dependency has been added, and if not, it may add it, resulting in the script being included twice.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript files should be cached. This is the first step to reduce the loading time. Moving JS files at the bottom will help but not that much if is your only action. Also you have to examine the possibility for using the defer attribute for your JS files, meaning that scripts are executed when the page has finished parsing.